# Setting each list item to 50% of the containers height (CSS) not working

Tags: html, css

Trying to set list item heights to 50% but doesn't seem to do anything.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y9mwk2ut/4/)

## HTML

```
<div class="list-container">

  <ul>
    <li id="item1">hello</li>
    <li id="item2">world</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

## CSS

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 100%;
  padding: none;
}

.list-container {
  height: 100%;
}

#item1 {
  height: 50%;
}

#item2 {
  height: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set html and body height first

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 100%;
  padding: none;
}
.list-container {
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
#item1 {
  height: 50%;
}
#item2 {
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-container">
  <ul>
    <li id="item1">hello</li>
    <li id="item2">world</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```